# MYSQL select rows when criteria in at least x colums is met?

Tags: mysql

Another MYSQL question where I could not find an answer:

I have this table and I want to to get all ID's which have SN>7 AND reps > 4 and where in columns 1-6 a certain criteria is met at least x times.

For example where at least 3 cells in columns col1-col6 have a value > 1.

The first part is easy (`SELECT * FROM table WHERE SN > 7 AND reps > 4....`) but I can't figure out second part.

Thanks!

```
ID SN    reps  col1   col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
A  12    3     0.6    1     3     -2    1     3
B  6     5     3.2    1.1   -3.3  3     0     0
C  300   6     1.3    -0.4  0     0.6   -0.5  -3.3
```

Comment: I guess that the second part you need to clarify it

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE SN > 7 AND reps > 4 and
      (case when `1` > 1 then 1 else 0 end +
       case when `2` > 1 then 1 else 0 end +
       case when `3` > 1 then 1 else 0 end +
       case when `4` > 1 then 1 else 0 end +
       case when `5` > 1 then 1 else 0 end +
       case when `6` > 1 then 1 else 0 end) >= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where sn> 7 and reps > 4 and 
(((`1` > 1) + (`2` > 1 ) + (`3` > 1) + (`4` > 1) + (`5` >1 ) + (`6` > 1)) >= 3)
```